# Code Changes in MVC4 app while moving Static Content to blob storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am moving my MVC4 application static data like(CSS,IMG,Javascript,etc) to Azure Blob storage enabled with CDN.
It will offload my server and in return will increase system Performance and responsiveness.

I have two queries here :

1. Will migrating static data to Blob actually increase Performance as compared to MVC4 bundling feature to deliver the content to browser.
2. What & How to accommodate the code changes involved in the process.How to change the Virtual Path to the Actual corresponding blob URI.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

**1. Will migrating static data to Blob actually increase Performance as compared to MVC4 bundling feature to deliver the content to browser.**

CDN and bundling will both improve performance. CDN will offload the load on your server and serve up the file from the closest data center thus ensuring high availability etc etc. With bundling the first time the page is loaded you will see it loading faster than if the files were not bundled. However once the page as been requested the browser caches the assets. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047981/how-to-upload-bundled-and-minified-files-to-windows-azure-cdn) question as well

**What & How to accommodate the code changes involved in the process.How to change the Virtual Path to the Actual corresponding blob URI.**

You will have to use the CDN url with the container name and blob name. Remember to have URL version suffixes that you can take off a config file or change if you use the CDN since any changes to your assets will not be reflected in the CDN unless you explicitly force it to refresh with a new version.