# How to automatically upload ASP.NET optimization generated bundles to CDN

Tags: asp.net, optimization, bundle

It is 2014, the ASP.NET Optimization framework is two years old. Is there any progress, could I easily upload the generated bundles to CDNs for example Azure CDN, or Amazon's Cloudfare?

If yes, please help me, how?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?  This looks like a related answer...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24410837/2011999

Answer (score 0):

This article was updated less than a month ago and gives steps to use and automate websites with azure CDN.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-serve-content-from-cdn-in-your-web-application/

Use the powershell script provided along with the bundling.UseCdn feature and this should be possible to automate.