# Azure CDN, .Net Bundling and Version String

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cdn, asp.net-bundling

In the out of the box .Net bundling calculates a version string, my guess is from a hash of the files in the bundles, thus if a file changes, the version string changes, and the cache gets busted.

I'm trying to utilize bundling and Azure CDN, but it looks like when I enable CDN with bundling, it breaks the version string now.

Microsoft's tutorial suggest using the Assembly version and auto-incrementing this, but I'd prefer not to do this, as the version string should only change when a file in the bundle changes.

Does anyone know how to use .Net bundling + CDN + OTB version string?

Document for how I setup CDN to work with Azure Web App
 - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-websites-with-cdn/

Comment: Do you want to auto update the file version using bundling on Azure CDN? I recommend you can refer to these workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047981/how-to-upload-bundled-and-minified-files-to-windows-azure-cdn/13736433

Comment: I setup the CDN using the following article.  I'm not uploading anything to storage. I believe it auto uploads when working with azure app services.

Comment: @TWilly did you managed to user version with bundled cdn .. I am into the same situation now .